# Difference between calling sys.exit() and throwing exception

Tags: python, exception

What is the difference between calling `sys.exit()` and throwing an exception in Python?

Let's say I have a Python script which does the following:

1. open a file
2. read lines
3. close it

If the file doesn't exist or an `IOException` gets thrown at runtime, which of the options below makes more sense?

1. no except/catch of the exception, if exception occurs, it fails out (which is expected behaviour anyway)
2. except/catch the exception, logs the error message, throw customized exception by myself, fails out.
3. in an `except IOException` block, exit with an error message e.g. `sys.exit("something is wrong")`

Does option 3 kill the process while 1 and 2 do not? What's the best way to handle the Python exceptions given that Python doesn't have a checked exception like Java (I am really a Java developer ^_^)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`sys.exit` raises a `SystemExit` itself so from a purely technical point of view there's no difference between raising that exception yourself or using `sys.exit`. And yes you can catch `SystemExit` exceptions like any other exception and ignore it.

So it's just a matter of documenting your intent better.

PS: Note that this also means that `sys.exit` is actually a pretty bad misnomer - because if you use `sys.exit` in a thread only the thread is terminated and nothing else. That can be pretty annoying, yes.

Answer (score 13):

There's a small, subtle difference:

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit()
except:
    print("Caught")
```

that `except` statement catches the exception whereas:

```
import sys

try:
    sys.exit()
except Exception:
    print("Caught")
```

exits without error. `SystemExit` exception (like `KeyboardInterrupt`) isn't caught by `except Exception`, but caught by `except` alone.

So if the caller catches everything with `except:` (which is bad practice), your `sys.exit` won't quit but will be considered as an "error". That's why `except Exception:` is better to be sure to catch all exceptions except CTRL+C and system exit (which are of the `BaseException` class).